# How can I get current view that has focus inside an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` that contains several `EditText` views. When a user clicks the **clear** button, the current view which has focus should be cleared from text.

I'm using the method `getCurrentFocus()` which returns a view and casting it to an `EditText`. However, the method always returns a **null**.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
DialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("Clear", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    ((EditText) this.getCurrentFocus()).setText("");
                }
            })
```

Comment: What do you get if you call it on the dialog instead? `((EditText)((Dialog)dialogInterface).getCurrentFocus()).setText("");`

Comment: @DanielZolnai Casting `dialogInterface` as a `Dialog` as you suggested did the trick. I only had to fix paranthesis. Thank you.

Comment: Added the comment as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the current focus on the dialog instead the activity.

To get the currently focused `View` on the `Dialog`, you can cast the `DialogInterface` to a `Dialog`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
    ((EditText) ((Dialog) dialogInterface).getCurrentFocus()).setText(""); 
}
```

Comment: There is an extra parenthesis that gives a syntax error. This is how it should be:  `((EditText) ((Dialog) dialogInterface).getCurrentFocus()).setText("");`